# How to know who is the maintainer of a GitHub repository?

Tags: github

Is there a way to know which people have merge privileges on a public GitHub repository. If the owner is a user and not an organization, then  at least I know one maintainer, but it's possible that there are other users with merge rights. Also, if the owner is an organization it is possible, that not all members of the organization have merge rights. So is there a way to find the exact maintainers?

Comment: You might try checking out if there's something available in [the GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/), I'm not sure though.

Comment: Could assume the "assignees" contains all the maintainers and owners?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Team privileges are not public in general. Even an organization-membership is not public since the publicity must be chosen by the given member, as the [Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/about-organization-membership) states:

> By default, your organization membership visibility is set to private. You can choose to publicize individual organization memberships on your profile.

This partly applies for their implementation of [CODEOWNERS](https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-code-owners), too. If it is up to date the given source file is annotated with a link to its responsible GitHub user.

---

However there's normally no need to know the individual maintainers of a repository (since every interaction with repos you're able to access is covered by the GitHub UI, which also assures that somebody takes care about your request). If your attention is about a public repository you might search the commits for accepted pull-request. But in that case you would preferably fork the repo and just generate pull-requests on your own.

You are even not able to contact an organization via GitHub - try to find their official website, contact them and ask for their maintainers if you need that information.

Comment: I guess the use case that OP may be asking about is "Is this repo maintained by a single maintainer who has since abandoned the project or are there multiple maintainers?"

Comment: I really hope the OP flagged this answer 8 years ago as answer because it answered his question. But your question is definitely a interesting one.

Comment: Only two upvotes, yet @Kewkimb answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73691673) seems to have answered the question for me today. Admittedly, only in an approximate way, but that's the best shot we seem to have when the `CODEOWNERS` file is absent.

Comment: You're only able to see people who decided to be visible and in this case "just" contributed to the code. This doesn't tell you if this person is able to merge something or is maintaining the repo. Even if you take a look into the MR-history this only gives you a clue about the past not the actual situation. In my opinion one should respect the maintainers decision of exposing contact information or not. Even if this means you have to wait far too long until somebody answers your issue.

Answer (score 17):

GitHub (since July 2017) now officially supports "code owners" for projects. Code owners are individuals or teams that are responsible for code in a repository.

Project maintainers can add a CODEOWNERS file to their repository to make it easier for others to identify code owners and have code owners be notified to review Issues and Pull Requests.

See the [announcement post](https://github.com/blog/2392-introducing-code-owners) and [help article](https://help.github.com/articles/about-codeowners/) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to the team members tab within your repo, on the right it will describe what type of member they are. Ex: member or owner.

[image: picture of the contributors section on the karma-coverage project]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can't find the team members tab, could you attach a screenshot to your answer or specify where exactly is located?

Comment: This is a good answer, and got me sleuthing enough to find what I need, I think. This and looking at commits to see who _committed_ or old PRs to see who merged and you'll get pretty close to knowing who does what -- and who might be a member of a managing group. @MarcoLackovic Added a picture. Does that help? It is from [the front page of a project](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage). There's also [a even more detailed page about contributors described here](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/viewing-activity-and-data-for-your-repository/viewing-a-projects-contributors).

Comment: @ruffin that's called **Contributors**, not "team members".

Comment: @MarcoLackovic I'm not sure what you're getting at in your comment. Did my earlier comment & screenshot answer your question about where to look, was it wrong, or did you need more information? If you're saying you ignored/missed Contributors initially because Kewkimb said "Team Members", I hope this helped. Possibly worth submitting/making an edit if that was the point of confusion.

Comment: @ruffin Yes, _team members_ was a point of confusion as there was no label named _team members_ in that page. As you are explaning how to find something to those who don't know where to look, I would simply name the section with it's actual name.

Answer (score 0):

The owners/maintainers may be listed in the following file within the repository:

```
.github/CODEOWNERS
```

This file is not mandatory and it's up to the owners/maintainers to add it and keep it up to date.

[Source](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners)

Comment: Legitimate question. I didn't downvote, but after looking for `CODEOWNERS` in the repositories that interest me today, I couldn't find any file with that name. I suppose you got some downvotes because repository owners don't bother setting up the codeowners file, and people trying your answer are therefore disappointed.

Comment: @ArnaudP good point, thanks. I edited my answer to clarify that.